# TSQL: How to Flatten a table by combining data into a single XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can I combine 2 tables into one flattened table (1 row per person) so that the columns retrieved from the first table appear as they were but the values in the second table are combined into a single XML column?

e.g. Table 1

| Person_gid | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary |
| 2 | Barry |
| 3 | Liam |

Table 2

| Person_gid | Subjects |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Physics |
| 1 | Chemistry |

How would I write a query to result in something like this:

| Person_gid | Name | Books |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | <Physics, Chemistry> |
| 2 | Barry |  |
| 3 | Liam |  |

I understand that I'll need to do a LEFT JOIN here but it's the XML bit that I need help with please.

Note: The XML won't look exactly like the above but I was having trouble writing XML in the markup that I used for the tables.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Technically, this is the opposite of "flattening", as you a producing rows with huge data "lumps" in them.  Normalization is the process of "flattening" data, this is denormalization, its opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @person TABLE (Person_gid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, person_name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @person (person_name) VALUES
('Mary'),
('Barry'),
('Liam');

DECLARE @subject TABLE (Person_gid INT, [subject] VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @subject (Person_gid, [subject]) VALUES
(1, 'Physics'),
(1, 'Chemistry');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.*, (
    SELECT subject FROM @subject AS s
    WHERE s.Person_gid = p.Person_gid
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root') 
) AS books
FROM @person AS p;
```

**Output**

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Person_gid | person_name |                          books                                      |
+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1 | Mary        | <root><subject>Physics</subject><subject>Chemistry</subject></root> |
|          2 | Barry       | NULL                                                                |
|          3 | Liam        | NULL                                                                |
+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```